# jQuery hover and Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, slideup

I have 20 different divs.

5 class="icon",

5 class="rainskin",

4 class="schoolproject",

4 class="wallpaper", &

2 class="miscellaneous".

Each div has one div with class=".type". I have the header portion (about 27 pixels) of the .type div showing, but the rest of it is hidden. When someone hovers over the .type div, it slides up (by changing the margin-top: to 0px). When the mouse no longer hovers it, it goes back down to its original spot (margin-top: 110px).

[Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gfefN/2/) and java code.

```
(function ($) {
    var original = [];
    $('.type').each(function (i) {
        original.push($(this).css('margin-top'));
    });
    $('.type').hover(function (e) {
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {"margin-top" : (
                $(this).parent().outerHeight() - 
                $(this).outerHeight()
            )},
            250
        );
    }, function (i){
        var i = $('.type').index($(this));
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {"margin-top": original[i]},
            250
        );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

It works perfectly fine, UNLESS someone hovers over one .type div, and goes to hover over another .type div BEFORE the first .type div slides back down. THEN the .icon, .rainkin, .schoolproject, etc. div is moved down a bit. [Go to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfefN/2/) and check it out yourself. I don't know why it's doing it.

Comment: if you feel like the backgrounds and such are necessary, [here's the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tibneo/gfefN/6/)

Comment: it seems to be working for me, which browser are you using?

Comment: im using google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use "margin-top" you're actually messing with the flow of the css divs, so if you use "top" rather , the position just applies to that div, you also need to set .type as "relative". One other thing, your original position can just be "0", and the amount to pull up can be the size of your .type div.

Check this modification out:

(Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/gfefN/9/ )

```
(function ($) {
    var original = [];
    $('.type').each(function (i) {
        original.push(0);
    });
    $('.type').hover(function (e) {
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {"top" : -(
                $(this).height()
            )},
            250
        );
    }, function (i){
        var i = $('.type').index($(this));
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {"top": original[i]},
            250
        );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: you didn't really change a whole lot. it works now. and i never realized that my problem was with the margin-top. thanks!!

Comment: is there anyway i can adjust how much it goes up when i hover over the .type divs?



[this is why, jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tibneo/gfefN/12/)

Comment: You mean that there's a space bellow?, if thats the case , it would be because you would need to substract the height of your <h1> to the amount to pixels to pull up, that way it doesnt show the emptyness.
http://jsfiddle.net/gfefN/13/

Comment: wow. jquery is a lot more versatile than i thought. thanks again!!